# Sentence without a main clause?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

What do you call a phrase without a main clause? For example, answering a question:

Are you to blame for the increase in deaths?

Of course not!

The answer cannot stand alone. Is there a name for this?

Edit: Above is not a good example.
I am trying to explain spoken language as a written text. The text is an interview. The interviewer has asked a question, and the answer starts with 'because' and refers to information in the question, and alone does not make sense. So it cannot stand alone. Does this make this a sentence fragment/subordinate clause or something else?

Comment: You mean something other than an answer or an utterance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sentences with no verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212822/sentences-with-no-verb)

Comment: It is a main clause, but one that has ellipsis of the subject pronoun and the auxiliary verb. In full, it would be "Of course I'm not!"

Answer (score 3):

Phrases such as *Of course not* can certainly stand alone, both in speaking and writing. But they are not fully-formed sentences of the type: *simple*, *compound* or *complex*.

The term for an incomplete sentence is *sentence fragment* or just *fragment*.  *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage* (p317) has this extract in the entry on *sentence*:

> **Sentence fragments**
>
> In ordinary conversation, the sentences uttered may not be
> fully-formed like those illustrated in section 1 above (i.e., *simple*,
> *compound* or *complex*). When taking turns to speak, conversationalists often produce sentences whose wording builds partly
> on the one before, without repeating every element.
>
> ...
>
> The use of sentence fragments and elliptical connections between them
> makes for highly efficient and highly cohesive discourse.

In your example, *Of course not* is an ellipsis of the fully-formed sentence:

> Of course I am not to blame for the increase in deaths.

---

In answer to the edited question, a stand-alone subordinate clause (dependent clause) is also called a *sentence fragment*. The *Longman Dictionary of Language Teaching and Applied Linguistics* (p522) has this entry on **sentence fragment**:

> (in composition) an incomplete sentence which cannot stand on its own.
>
> For example:
>
> *Whenever I try to hold a conversation with my parents about my career* is a sentence fragment because it is a *dependent clause*
> which contains a *subordinating conjunction* and should therefore be
> connected to an *independent clause*.

Comment: @Johanna Clark. Please see my edited answer above.

Comment: 'Stand alone' is perhaps not exactly the right term, given that there needs to be related (usually prior) context.

Comment: @JohannaClark It's not a fragment. It's a main clause with radical ellipsis. In this case the subject pronoun and the auxiliary verb are ellipted. It's okay in casual style.

Comment: I would say that _Of course not!_ is the fragment that results from the radical ellipting of subject 
and copula. _Owl at Purdue_ says: _Some fragments are not clearly pieces of sentences that have been left unattached to the main clause*; they are written as main clauses but lack a subject or main verb._ (*i.e., as 'stand-alone' subordinate clauses). https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/620/01/