# Categorizing sentences with lots of "the"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, is-it-a-sentence

Consider the following sentence: "The higher the price the better the quality." I've certainly heard people say similar sentences before (in terms of sentence structure). How would one categorize a sentence like this?

A similar question was posted here: [Sentences with no verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212822/sentences-with-no-verb). It gives the example of "System shutdown in 60 seconds." but that seems qualitatively different from the example I have. Would one still classify "The higher [..]" as a [nominal sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_sentence), which is the suggestion in the most upvoted answer there?